# To check whether index of list exists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Is there any solution to check whether index of list exists?

Other than:

1. using `len(list)`
2. using

   ```
   try:
      ...
   except IndexError:
      ...
   ```

As dict has a `dict.has_key(key)` to check whether key exists, is there any method to check index for list?

Comment: You have the two methods already. Note that `len(list)` is cheap.

Comment: Note: `dict.has_key()` has been deprecated. Use membership testing with `in` instead: `key in dict`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters May be worth noting, though, that for dicts, `in` checks whether the key is "in", while for lists it checks whether the value is "in".

Comment: @tobias_k: I did not advocate that membership testing with `in` on lists is an alternative method to what the OP is looking for. I am merely pointing out that `dict.has_key()` has been deprecated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Certainly not, but in the context of the question it _could_ be understood that way. ;-)

Comment: I am sorry you didn't find my answer to be helpful; however, there *are no additional methods to test*. Downvotes are not going to alter that.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are no additional methods to test if an index exists.

Dictionary keys are not easily predicted; you *have* to have a membership test to determine if a key exists efficiently, as scanning through all keys would be inefficient.

Lists do not suffer from that problem; `len(somelist)` is cheap (the length is cached on the list object), so `index < len(somelist)` is *the* way to test if an index exists, with exception handling a great fallback if you expect the index to be within the list boundaries most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehensions.

```
index in [someList.index(item) for item in someList]:
```

This will return true if there are at least `index` items in the list.

For dictionaries you could do something similar:

```
index in [someDictionary.keys().index(item) for item in someDictionary.keys()]
```

It's worth pointing out that this really is a moot point since using `len(list)` or `try ... except` works perfectly well.  But hey, you asked for another way, so here's another way.

Comment: This is very lengthy operation. Developer want simplicity not complexity. And, It is simple question that which is the other option other than len and try-catch.

Comment: You asked for an option besides len and try, that's what I gave you.  You ruled out the best answer (len), so any other suggestions are going to be lengthy operations.

Comment: I just want to know, is there any other existing method or functionality to perform this.

Comment: Boy, answer the question the way the OP posted it and you get downvoted for your trouble! +1 for the effort. Another +1 for the patience, but I can only +1.