# How to check if tuple has element?

Tags: python

I have an exception from which I'm trying to get args, but if fails.

```
print hasattr(e, 'args')
print type(e.args)
print hasattr(e.args, '1')
print hasattr(e.args, '0')
print '1' in e.args
print '0' in e.args
print 1 in e.args
print 0 in e.args
print e.args[0]
print e.args[1]
```

This prints:

```
True
<type 'tuple'>
False
False
False
False
False
False
Devices not found
4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [To check whether index of list exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565745/to-check-whether-index-of-list-exists)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. You want to check if `e.args[N]` exists or you want to check if a specific value is part of `e.args`?

Comment: @netcoder fist, if `e.args[0]` exists

Comment: Just check then length of `e.args`. If `len(e.args) == 1` then `e.args[0]` exists, if `len(e.args) == 2`, then `e.args[1]` exists, and so on. You cannot have empty elements in tuples and they are zero-indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You simply use the `in` operator:

```
>>> try:
...   raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
... except Exception as inst:
...   print inst.args
...   print 'spam' in inst.args
... 
('spam', 'eggs')
True
```

If your code is returning `False` then most likely `1` wasn't an argument to the exception. Perhaps post the code where the exception was raised.

You can check if the tuple has positions `0` to `N` by doing `len`.

Comment: as you can see `print e.args[0]` prints the result so i need to check just if [0] exists or not

Comment: Why not check if the `len` of the tuple. Then you know which indexes are present (up to `len-1`)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of your tuple:

```
t = 1, 2, 3,
if len(t) >= 1:
    value = t[0]    # no error there
```

...or you can just check for an `IndexError`, which I'd say is more pythonic:

```
t = 1, 2, 3,
try:
    value = t[4]
except IndexError:
    # handle error case
    pass
```

The latter is a concept named [EAFP: *Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python), which is a well known and common Python coding style.